# AWS account terminated, still accessing sites hosted on ec2 machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services

**I have terminated my account, but I am still able to access "http://somedomain.com", that is hosted on the ec2 machine of same terminated AWS account?**

Please explain why this is happening?
How can I terminate all services associated with this account, I am not able to login to console now.

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache? Does the website use service workers? Do you have a CDN which is replying with cached results?

Comment: how much time have passed after you have terminated your account

Comment: according to this document aws might retain the content after the post closure period https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/close-account.html

Comment: Was this built on a free tier ec2?

Comment: Yes, the build was on free tier ec2 with tomcat install behind an apache installed on the same ec2, it's been more than 12 hours.

Comment: I have access to my billing page only, and i can see cost increasing there per hour